# Xcode > Symbolic Breakpoint > Log Message > prints class of object property instead of value

Tags: xcode, symbolic-breakpoint

I have created a symbolic breakpoint in Xcode 11.3.1 to log the `name` property of the first parameter ($rdx) to an Objective-C method.  Although my expression:

```
(NSString*)[(NSRelationshipDescription*)$rdx name]
```

prints the expected value when passed via the `print object` (`po`) command, the message logged by the breakpoint prints instead

```
class name = _PFEncodedString
```

It also logs the value as expected if I enter a *Debugger Command* (with `po`) instead of *Log Message* as the breakpoint *Action*.  But of course that omits my label (unless I were to try to print a formatted string – what a kludge!), and it prints an extra blank line.  I was hoping *Log Message* would be helpful in debugging a difficult problem.

Am I doing something wrong or is Xcode's *Log Message* just broken?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one has answered after a week, I conclude that this is a bug in Xcode.  I have submitted it to Apple in FB7585394.